# PHP trigger_error() and utf8 characters?

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm using Apache + mod_php, and I've noticed that when I use trigger_error in PHP, and put some non us-western chacarter in string of the message, it gets written to apache error_log incorrectly.

For example, this line:

```
<?php trigger_error("Greška", E_USER_WARNING); ?>
```

dumps following line in error_log:

```
PHP Warning:  Gre\xc5\xa1ka in /var/www/jsosic.php on line 1
```

Is this something that can be rectified or should I simply stop using non us-western characters in trigger_error calls?

(For anyone interested, "Greska" stands for error in my native language - Croatian).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the encoding of the log file is not utf8. I don't know of a way to correct that.

You can use `set_error_handler` to define your own error handler that will log errors in utf8.

Comment: If I try this on command line, it spits the message out in UTF8. It looks to me like it's the problem with mod_php.

Comment: Undoubtedly so, and I don't know how to correct that.

Comment: I'll try to dig through libphp5.so code, maybe I can stumble upon some hidden php gem :-/ sigh